# Front End Performance testing Automation

Tags: jenkins-plugins, performance-testing, ui-automation, lighthouse

Currently little to no front end performance testing done on our enterprise web application (Java, Hibernate, Oracle, HTML/CSS/JavaScript & In-house templating language).

We recently setup Jenkins and are slowly trying to automate things.

I know straight off the main problem points with our front end performance (No Minifying, compression, bundling, etc.....)

Application is built nightly via a jenkins task. (Using Maven)
I'd like to use a tool to identify current baseline metrics and going forward have tests run nightly and alert if baseline values are exceeded.

I had a quick look at [Lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) and notice it provides a nodejs module for running on command line as well as it been possible to run as a grunt task via jenkins.
[This](https://kitconcept.com/blog/continuous-performance-analysis-with-lighthouse-and-jenkins/) article was useful on setup.

Has anyone experience using this approach with these tools?
Any suggested better approach?

Initially, we are looking for basics for the most widely hit parts of application. (Page load time, file sizes, http requests on page).

I can also see us using it to keep manners on accessibility of site as this is kinda important too for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a load testing tool which will mimic real-life usage of your application and report metrics like

- average/min/max/median/90/95/99 percentile response times
- percentage of errors
- throughput in requests per unit of time
- sent bytes
- received bytes
- etc.

A good candidate could be [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it's pure Java-based multiprotocol load testing tool which can support both web interface and oracle database load testing. It can be integrated with Jenkins via [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin), check out [How to Use the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) for more details.

---

If you are interested in front-end testing only (page rendering time, dom events processing, scripts execution time, etc.) you can consider using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) browser automation framework together with [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the WebPageTest API, which includes Lighthouse results as well as it's own and will avoid having to setup any local testing frameworks: https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/advanced-features/webpagetest-restful-apis

You can also install your own local copy if you want: https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest-docs/blob/master/user/Private%20Instances/README.md

This is the tool set I use to automate my testing.